# Angle α lies in quadrant II, and tanα=−125. Angle β lies in quadrant IV, and cosβ=35. What is the exact value of sin(α+β)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

Angle $\alpha$ lies in quadrant II, and $\tan(\alpha)=−12/5$. Angle $\beta$ lies in quadrant IV, and $\cos\beta=3/5$.

What is the exact value of $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$?

The answer must be answered using trigonometric identities. There is no further information, nor graphs are given.

SOURCE: FUELED.BRIGHTSPACE.COM  (ONLINE SCHOOLING)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I just worked backward by finding the individual terms of tangent and cosine, by using tan(a)=-12/5 and cos(b)=3/5. Which was equivalent to 112.6199 and 53.1301 (rounded). Then subtracted them from 180, getting the leftover 14.2500 deg, which I assumed would be the sine

Comment: Post everything you have done to attempt solving the problem in your post and please use mathjax to typeset your equations. Questions that show no attempt and don't use mathjax will get closed, which I'm sure is not the outcome you intend!

Comment: Hi Jazmine. Hendrickson is right, the stuff you posted as a comment (your specific calculations) should be placed in your main post. Click "Edit" above, thanks.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you for the advice there, I'll get pictures on and reformat my equations now

Comment: The method that your question shows you using can not get an exact answer. You need to get exact vales for $\sin\alpha$and $\cos\alpha$, and you need to get an exact value for $\sin\beta$. All of these will be rational numbers with denominator $5$. Then use the trigonometric formula for $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: Use the formula $\tan^2(\alpha) + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\alpha)}$ plus the fact that $\alpha$ lies in quadrant $2$ to compute $\cos(\alpha), \sin(\alpha)$.  Then use the fact that $\cos(\beta)$ is known plus the fact that $\beta$ lies in quadrant $4$ to compute $\sin(\beta)$.  At this point, it is **game over**, since $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha).$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Let $a$ be the opposite side, $b$ be the adjacent side, and $c$ be the hypotenuse. Use the Pythagorean Theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ to find the missing sides.
2. $\sin A = \dfrac {a}{c}$, $\cos A = \dfrac {b}{c}$, and $\tan A = \dfrac {a}{b}$.  With the information you've found in (1), you should be able to find $\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha, \sin \beta \text { and} \cos \beta.$
3. Finally, $\sin (\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta$.